# Jquery Ajax get works in Chrome but not in IE or FF

Tags: jquery

I have this code which works fine in  Chrome but not in IE or FF.
The [babj](http://www.bajb.net/2010/02/browser-back-button-detection/) is a javascript library.

```
$(function() {
    bajb_backdetect.OnBack = function() {
        // alert('Returning back');
        $.get('/url');
    };
```

Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is to load the Back page with the values that it had by making a call to the server for that url.
In Chrome it is working fine but in IE and FF, the call to the server does not propogate and when I interact with any of the controls, the event fires and the page reloads.

Comment: ) is missing before last semicolon.

Comment: Thanks @Sudz. I made an error in my post. The code had the correct brackets.